# How do I prevent the css in one component from affecting the css in another component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React, so I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. Using the React Router, I have three routes, `/`, `/signup`, and `/login`, and the importing of css in each component spills over into the css of the other components, ruining the styling. In this case, instead of the div element `word` being the color as described in each component's css, they all come out green which should only happen for the Signup component. What can I do to fix this?

App.js

```
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage/HomePage'
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage/LoginPage'
import SignupPage from './pages/SignupPage/SignupPage'
import  {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/> 
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={HomePage}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

LoginPage.js

```
import { React } from 'react'
import "./LoginPage.css"

export default function LoginPage(){
    return(
      //In css file, word is red, but comes out green instead
      <div className="word">login</div>
    )
}
```

SignupPage.js

```
import { React } from 'react'
import "./SignupPage.css"

export default function SignupPage(){
    return(
      //In css file, word is green
      <div className="word">signup</div>
    )
}
```

HomePage.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import "./HomePage.css"

export default function HomePage() {

    return (
         //In css file, word is hotpink, but comes out green instead
         <div className="word">Home</div>
    )
```

Is there something I need to add to my App.js file?

Comment: It’s unclear what the underlying issue is. Why is the styling so different it creates problems? What specifically *is* is the problem?

Comment: I'll try to be as descriptive as I can, describing my issue is a little harder than I thought. The problem I'm having is that on each route, the css of each component is spilling over into the other components. For example, simply adding the element `<div className="word">example</div>` to each component and changing its color to red, blue, and yellow respectively in the css files results in `example` being green in each route. Does that clarify anything?

Comment: I think sharing your CSS definitions will help understand the issue

Comment: @DarienMiller there are several ways to fix this like CSS modules, styled-components or having a parent class that's unique to each component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a top div for each page:

```
export default function HomePage() {
return (
     <div className="homepage"><div className="word">Home</div></div>
)
```

Do similarly for signup page.

Then in css

homepage.css

```
 .homepage .word{
     
      color:red;
    
  }
```

signup.css

```
.signup .word{
 
  color:green;

 }
```

Now depending if you use `word` class inside `signup` page or `homepage` (any level deep), `word` will have different styling.

Comment: This solution actually worked out for me perfectly, but coming from html + css + raw Javascript, I'm curious as to why I need to wrap the code in a larger parent div in order for the css in each component to not mix in with the other components.

Comment: @DarienMiller react doesn't scope the css based on components AFAIK.

Comment: Ahh, understand! That makes sense, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to prevent that is by using CSS Modules because **CSS Modules** let you use the same CSS class name in different files without worrying about naming clashes

Using CSS module is simple, just follow it's naming convention which looks like this, `[name].module.css`

Example: CSS className selectors of the following CSS modules, are independently

`App.module.css`

```
.container{
  color: #fff;
}
```

`Navigation.module.css`

```
.container{
  color: #000;
}
```

[Click here to read more about CSS modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, one thing I want to add is module css would not apply to direct html element styling, i.e `input[type="file"]` would be also applied to all components.